# Combine all words into one line separated by semicolon (AWK|SED)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, merge

Hello guys need some help with this. As a curl output to the file I have the following:

```
FINISHED
JOB#1
20140428 0016
FINISHED
JOB#2
20140428 0015
```

Is there a way to merge these lines the following way:

```
JOB#1;0015;20140428;FINISHED
JOB#2;0016;20140428;FINISHED
JOB#3;0017;20140428;FINISHED
```

And so on...

I tried:

```
paste -d, -s filenew.com
```

Comment: Please show what you tried. It should be straightforward using `awk`.

Comment: I used the paste -d, -s myfile.txt, but it just merged all the lines in one

Comment: `paste` is for combining lines from multiple input files. I don't think it does anything useful with one input.

Comment: `FINISHED` is first in the input, but it's last in the output?

Comment: That is correct, FINISHED is fist and is a separate line in the input related to the two lines below: job #, date and sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `gawk` (GNU awk) or `mawk`:

```
awk -v RS='FINISHED' -v OFS=';' '$0 { print $1, $3, $2, RS }' file
```

Sadly, this won't work with FreeBSD/OSX `awk` or strictly POSIX-compliant versions, because they don't support multi-character input-record separators (`RS`).

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN { finished=""; job=""; ff1=""; ff2=""; }
{
  if(finished == "") { finished = $0""; next; }
  if(job == "") { job = $0""; next; }
  if(ff1 == "") { ff1 = $2""; ff2 = $1""; printf("%s;%s;%s;%s\n", job,ff1,ff2,finished);
    finished="";job="";ff1="";ff2="";
  }
}
END { }
```

awk -f formatter.awk inputfile

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't rely on non-POSIX extensions, but you can simplify it: (a) No need to initialize the variables, so you can do without the `BEGIN` block (and without the empty `END` block). (b) No need for variables `ff1` and `ff2`, because they're only used in _one_ block - use `$1` and `$2` directly. (c) take advantage of multi-variable assignments (e.g., `finished=job=""`). This gives us: `awk '{ if (finished == "") { finished = $0; next } if (job == "") { job = $0; next } printf("%s;%s;%s;%s\n", job, $2, $1, finished); finished=job="" }' inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;N;s/(.*)\n(.*)\n(.*) (.*)/\2;\3;\4;\1/' file
```

Read 3 lines in at a time and re-arrange the contents.

Comment: +1; if you use `-E` instead of `-r`, it'll work on FreeBSD/OSX, too.

Answer (score 1):

*posix* awk supports `getline` so:

```
$ awk --posix -v OFS=';' '
    {Status = $0; getline Job; getline; Date = $1; Time = $2;
    print Job, Time, Date, Status;}' file.txt
JOB#1;0016;20140428;FINISHED
JOB#2;0015;20140428;FINISHED
```

Comment: +1, but a strictly POSIX-compliant `awk` doesn't support `--posix` :)(FreeBSD `awk` will choke on that, for instance; seems to work fine if you just omit the `--posix`)

Comment: @mklement0 `--posix` is for proof of concept. I don't have access to other distros to check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^FINISHED/ && job { printf("%s;%s;%s;%s\n", job, num, date, $0); job = "" }
     /^JOB/ { job = $0 }
     /^[0-9]+ [0-9]+$/ { num = $2; date = $1; }
     END { if (job) { printf("%s;%s;%s;%s\n", job, num, date, $0); } }'
```

Comment: This won't work, because `$0` in the `END` block won't be `FINISHED`; you could finagle it by replacing it with a literal `"FINISHED`".

Answer (score 0):

Serg12, I'm assuming you have a typo and that you meant that the output should be:

```
JOB#1;0016;20140428;FINISHED
JOB#2;0015;20140428;FINISHED
```

i.e., 0016 on the first line and 0015 in the second one. With sed you can also do:

```
sed -n "/FINISHED/ n;h;N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\) \(.*\)/\1;\3;\2;FINISHED/p" file
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple, portable `awk` version:

```
awk '/^2014/ {print x,$2,$1,y} {y=x;x=$0}' OFS=";" file
JOB#1;0016;20140428;FINISHED
JOB#2;0015;20140428;FINISHED
```

Comment: Clever, but I suggest using `awk '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ {print x,$2,$1,y} {y=x;x=$0}' OFS=";" file` so it'll work next year, too :) (I've avoided `[0-9]{4}`, because in GNU `awk` < `4` that would require the `--re-interval` option.)

Comment: @mklement0 or just `/^20[0-9][0-9]/` that will cover 100 years.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variation.

```
tr \n' ';' <file | sed 's/\(;FINISHED\);/\1\n/g'
```

However, some legacy `sed` implementations would choke on long input lines (ISTR old BSD would segfault already on lines longer than 256 characters).